# GWT-comet build fails with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, gwt, comet

I've tried to setup GWT-comet using the official guide(http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/wiki/GettingStarted). What I did:

1. Add gwt-comet-1.2.3.jar to project and build path.
2. Setup the basic client and server code.
3. Inherit the required module.

`< inherits name='net.zschech.gwt.comet.Comet'/>`

The crash is obviously related to the inheriting the module. Stack trace:

```
Loading modules
   com.MyApp.Test
      Loading inherited module 'com.MyApp.Test'
         Loading inherited module 'net.zschech.gwt.comet.Comet'
            [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/ext/GeneratorExt
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$ClassAttrCvt.convertToArg(ModuleDefSchema.java:888)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerArgs.convertToArg(HandlerArgs.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:221)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1026)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:570)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:456)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1094)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExt
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 59 more
         [ERROR] Line 11: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:336)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1026)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:570)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:456)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1094)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
         [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onHandlerException(DefaultSchema.java:58)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:240)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1026)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:570)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:456)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1094)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
         [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:371)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1026)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:570)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:456)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1094)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

Any idea why this occurs? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gwt-comet-1.2.3.jar is not compatible with GWT 2.5.0-rc1 (or higher).

so you need to upgrade the gwt-comet version to 1.2.5.

link : https://gwt-comet.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=330005000&name=gwt-comet-1.2.5.jar&token=St1Wda3HoyBJfRyZZ-Vq3zQibKo%3A1398940143165

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a space that's why you are getting below exception:

> [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
>
> [ERROR] Line 11: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'

use

```
<inherits name="net.zschech.gwt.comet.Comet" />
```

instead of

```
< inherits name="net.zschech.gwt.comet.Comet" />
```

---

--EDIT--

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExt

Look at below discussions on Google-web-toolkit

- [NoClassDefFoundError: GeneratorExt with 2.5.0 FINAL](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7820)
- [Can't launch SuperDevMode on project: NoClassDefFoundError: GeneratorExt](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7626)

Comment: I've added the space to the SO post, otherwise it's not getting displayed. Should've mentioned it, I guess.

Comment: Look at `[ERROR] Line 11: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'`

Comment: The message you quoted means that the build failed while trying to load the module. My inherits tag looks the same as yours. The space you are talking about doesn't exist in my .gwt.xml file, but only in this post since the original tag wouldn't show(because of the way StackOverflow parses characters). About your update: Hmm... Could it be that gwt-comet isn't compatible with GWT 2.6?

Comment: I can't say. I think you would get the answer on the above mentioned link.

Comment: Look at this link [http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7626](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7626)